# How to create buffer similar to *compilation* in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have an asynchronous process in Emacs, which creates a TAGS file.

This process creates a process buffer called *ctags*. If the process result is "finished\n", I kill the buffer.

If the process result is anything else I want to display the process buffer similar to the *compilation* status output when running *M-x compile*.

I.e. I want to vertically split the screen and show the *ctags* buffer at the bottom. Pressing *q* would preferably *kill* the bottom buffer and just show my original buffer.

I tried using this in my process sentinel callback:

```
(split-window-vertically)
(set-window-buffer (selected-window) (get-buffer "*ctags*"))
```

but aside from the fact that it puts the *ctags* buffer on top, the buffer does not have the same characteristics as the *compilation* output, e.g. pressing *q* inserts q.

How do I create a buffer like *compilation*?

**EDIT:**

Inspired by Trey Jackson's answer below, this does exactly what I want:

```
(pop-to-buffer (get-buffer "*ctags*"))
(compilation-mode)
```

It selects the *ctags* buffer, puts it into compilation mode and *q* will quit the window.

**EDIT2:**
Using

```
(compilation-mode)
```

(major mode instead of minor mode) since Emacs somehow doesn't like reapplying the minor mode to an exisiting buffer.

The Error message I get is:

```
Toggling compilation-minor-mode off; better pass explicit argument.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the behavior of the `*compilation*` buffer, add this to your script:

```
(compilation-mode)
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I needed. For completeness sake, (compilation-minor-mode) works as well.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to derive your own mode from compilation-mode, and define error regex, etc.