# Compilation buffer like "pop-up" buffer

Tags: emacs, popup

I want to create a buffer that will behave like a pop-up buffer.

#### Wanted Features

- It should be closed with ESC.
- It should kill window when a buffer is killed (Could also do with a hook but if there's
  builtin version it would be better)

#### Restrictions

I use evil-mode and I don't want to use external packages.

### Things I've Done:

- It should be on the bottom of the frame.

```lisp
(display-buffer (get-buffer-create "*kmonad-scratchpad*")
                '(display-buffer-at-bottom (window-height . 0.15)))
```

- It should be immediately focused.

```lisp
(pop-to-buffer "*kmonad-scratchpad*")
```

Looked at `compile.el` but couldn't find how it's implemented.

#### Differences with similar questions:

- [How to create buffer similar to *compilation* in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251503/how-to-create-buffer-similar-to-compilation-in-emacs) Mine needs to be writable, it messes with evil mode.
- [Emacs: pop-up bottom window for temporary buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034839/emacs-pop-up-bottom-window-for-temporary-buffers) Don't want to use `popwin.el`